# sample n8n workflow to post data to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, n8n

I'm new to n8n and I'm trying to create a workflow which posts data received in a webhook to google sheets. I tried searching for multiple sources but didn't find anything easy to configure. can someone please guide me with the same?

I tried configuring webhook and created a google sheet but data is not getting posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posting data to google sheets, first you need to create a oauth credentials and add the token to your n8n, follow this [link](https://docs.n8n.io/integrations/builtin/credentials/google/oauth-generic/#create-a-new-credential-in-n8n) for more info on oauth credentials for google sheets.

The following link is an example [workflow](https://n8n.io/workflows/694-transform-data-in-google-sheets/) for posting data to google sheets.